# ImageBackground is not taking full height of View in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image

I am using `ImageBackground` in my react native app, but it not covering full height of the `View`

[image]

You can see that there is red space which is not covered by my image.

Below is my code:

```
<View
  style={styles.subDomainItem}>
  <ImageBackground
    resizeMode={'cover'}
    source={ImageConfig.script_default_cloud}
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      height: (dimensions.width - 20) / 2,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}></ImageBackground>
</View>

subDomainItem: {
    maxWidth: '94%',
    width: '94%',
    marginHorizontal: '3%',
    marginVertical: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderRadius: 10,
    flex: 1,
    elevation: 8,
  },
```

I want my image to cover all the red spaces at top and bottom, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Yes but you wrote `height: (dimensions.width - 20) / 2,`... Have you tried `height: 100%`?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito giving `height:'100%'`, is making the `View` disappear

Comment: Ok try to remove height property. What do you see?

Comment: It's making `View` disappear

Comment: Ok could you reproduce your error in codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to give a height and width for ImageBackground if you want to cover all space of parent View you just need give flex: 1 or height and width to 100% for ImageBackground.

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  ImageBackground,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('screen').width;
const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('screen').height;

const MainPage = () => {
   return (
     <View style={styles.subDomainItem}>
        <ImageBackground
            resizeMode="contain"
            source={ImageConfig.script_default_cloud}
            style={styles.bgImageStyle}
        >
            <Text>Sample</Text>
      </ImageBackground>
   </View>
);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  subDomainItem: {
      width: WIDTH,
      height: HEIGHT,
      alignItems: 'center',
  },
  bgImageStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    width: WIDTH,
    height: HEIGHT,
  }
})
```

Comment: I have tried both the options, but it's not working

Comment: I have updated the answer please check it

Answer (score 0):

**Try this. is wroking fine**

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, ImageBackground,Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native'

const Backimage =  () => {
    return(
        <ImageBackground 
            style={{width:Dimensions.get("screen").width, height:Dimensions.get("screen").height}}
            source={require("./src/assets/water.png")} resizeMethod="resize">
            
        </ImageBackground>
    )
}

export default Backimage
```

Comment: yes I have tried this, but it's not working

Comment: try to put `ImageBackground` inside `<View style={[styles.subDomainItem]}>`, because I don't want the image on whole screen, it should be inside the given `View`.

Comment: I have tested this solution. it is working fine.

Comment: no, its not covering all the area, add `backgroundColor: 'red'`, then you can see that there is still that red area

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give your subDomainItem view an explicit height when styling it. You gave it a width of 94% but you haven‘t specified a height.

ImageBackground should then work properly by giving it a height of 100% if the parent component (subDomainItem in this case) has an explicit height.

Answer (score 0):

if Style of status bar is auto then you need to add that height to the dimensions so that you can get the height of the screen for any screen size

import { Dimensions, StatusBar } from 'react-native'

**const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height + StatusBar.currentHeight;**

Then use it in the program like

<View style={{ height: HEIGHT, width: "100%" }} >

Comment: Code needs formatting